# How was this picture of a model on a boat with a sunset in the background created?

Tags: reverse-engineering

It's so bright and the colors and detail stand out so much. I have a NikonD5200 and access to Photoshop.

Source: http://angelicablick.se/blog/2014/06/13/call-magic/ (first image)

Comment: From the light on the model in the 3rd foto I would also expect the use of some flash gun from the left

Comment: Assuming that this is not a composite created from several different pictures (there seem to be no clear indications of that in this picture) there has been a quite some work that was put into that image. This is definitely not just a quick snapshot but a well planned and edited professional shot.
1st a strong light source from "behind" (otherwise part of the models and inside of the boat would be in shadow) and 2nd quite some post-processing (skin, clothes)

Answer (score 8):

This looks very much like a the photographer duplicated the image as a new layer, used a large radius Gaussian blur, and then set the blending mode to "overlay". It's the same effect I used in this photo:

[image]

You get a soft focus effect but with crisp details, and a boost to the saturation. They have also reduced the contrast by bringing the black point up a bit, and possibly put some blue in the shadows (seperate R G and B curves is a good way to achieve this).

You need a decent-ish image to start with, shooting with the sun that low in the sky certainly helps. But there's nothing there you couldn't do with your D5200, provided you have a boat and some willing models!

Answer (score 4):

There's a definite "HDR feel" to the photos, but I'm not sure if any actual HDR / exposure blending tricks have actually been used — it might just be strong curves and saturation adjustment, combined with odd lighting.

- The photo has been taken against the light, but with the sun low in the sky and behind a layer of clouds, which will tend to diffuse the light and somewhat reduce the contrast difference between the foreground and the sky.  I suspect that's really the most important "trick" here.
- The photographer may have used a [polarizing filter](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizing_filter_%28photography%29) to darken the sky and the reflected sunlight off the water.  There may also have been a [fill flash](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fill_flash) involved.
- It's pretty likely that the [luminance curve](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_%28tonality%29) has been adjusted to add contrast to the shadows (possibly using something like the Photoshop "Shadow / Highlight" tool, rather than by directly editing the curve), and the [color saturation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness) has obviously been increased.

  It's *possible* that some of the adjustment may have been masked to affect only the foreground, but it's hard to tell for sure.  The images *could* also be [exposure fused](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_Fusion) composites, with the sky and the foreground taken from separate [bracketed](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing) images (or the same RAW image with different exposure corrections), but I actually suspect that, in this case, they're not (see below).
- Looking at the sky, especially in the second picture, you can tell that the highlights are pretty badly clipped, and it appears to be a sharp "digital clip" rather than a smooth "film clip".

  I would consider this a flaw (even if it does add somewhat to the "dramatic" contrast), but it also suggests to me that the photos have probably *not* been processed too much (beyond the obvious contrast and saturation boosts) — or, alternatively, that whoever post-processed them wasn't skilled enough to handle the highlights properly.

---

Anyway, here's a quick example of how to post-process such images to bring out the foreground.  The original image is a quick snapshot I took from a boat against the sunlight, with no fill flash, using a Nikon D70s at ISO 200, f/6.0, 1/8000 s.  It lacks the dramatic sunset colors, but does illustrate the general issues with shooting against the light over water:

[image: Step 1: Original image with no exposure correction]
[image: Step 2: Exposure boosted by +2.6 in ufraw]
[image: Step 3: Color saturation boosted to 170%]
[image: Step 4: Luminance curve adjusted to balance foreground and background]
<sub>Top down, left to right: (1) original image with no exposure correction, (2) exposure boosted by +2.6 in ufraw, (3) color saturation boosted to 170%, (4) luminance curve adjusted to balance foreground and background.</sub>

Note how, without exposure correction, the foreground is severely underexposed.  That's actually deliberate; it's a lot easier to boost exposure in post than to fix blown highlights.

All of this was done with global adjustments only; of course, with careful masking, much more would be possible.  The tricky part here was getting the curve adjustment to look good.  Here's a screenshot of the curve I ended up using:

[image: Screenshot of color curves in ufraw]

You can see that there's a strong contrast boost at the bottom end (corresponding to the subject in the foreground), with a compensating flat range in the "midtones" (which, here, basically means the constrast gap between the foreground and background) and a slight S-curve in the upper range corresponding to the highlights on the water (to give them a bit more contrast).

As for dramatic lighting, I'd say it comes mostly down to picking the right time and location.  Here's the kind of background you can get with a polarizing filter and the sun low behind clouds:

[image: Sun behind clouds, taken with a cellphone camera through sunglasses]

This is, in fact, a completely unedited photo taken with an old 0.3 Mpx cellphone camera, filtered through polarizing sunglasses.  You can just imagine how awesome it would've looked if I'd had a *proper* camera with me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a combination of a number of factors:

- Lighting: to balance the light from the sun, off camera flash or a large reflector will have been used.
- A professional-level camera and lens: the sharpness and overall quality of the image suggests pro-level equipment. But that's not a given.
- Post-processing: saturation, contrast and sharpness (amongst other things) have all been enhanced considerably.

You could take a shot like this with your D5200 and a decent lens - all you need is two gorgeous women and a yacht.

Comment: How on earth can you tell the sharpness of this image from a 1024 x 682 sample? I've had completely out of focus images that look just fine when downsampled to this resolution and sharpened. I can't see anything to suggest any particularly capable gear was used, just some very evident post processing.

Comment: Just a feeling - I did say _suggests_ and point out that it was by no means a given. Also, the guy's on a yacht with two models: I doubt he's using a Casio P&S

Answer (score 1):

This mostly just looks slightly over saturated.  Might be some additional curves work on it or a slight artificial exposure gradient added on the right hand side possibly.

Comment: Looks low contrast to me, there are no pure blacks or whites in the image that I can see.

Comment: @mattgrum hmm looking again I agree now. When I first looked I was looking primarily at the sky. Perhaps just a saturation boost then.

Answer (score 0):

If I was planning this shot I would have used two things:

1. a reverse graduated Neutral Density Filter - they are made very
   specifically for this type of shot, and
2. Gyro stabilizer(s) - to keep the camera relatively stable for a blur free shot

Answer (score 0):

In pics 1 & 3 exposed for the background so it isn't clipped and then pushed the foreground in PP?  Maybe the similar in pic 2 but background is clipped.  Maybe some fill flash or reflector but i can't see the source reflected in the sunglasses.